# Fallout 4 on Steam not launching?

Tags: fallout-4

Ok. So I bought Fallout 4 again on another account on Steam. It downloaded and installed and what have you. When I went to launch the game, the launcher appeared as normal, but when you clicked play. The game gave me a black screen and then kicked me out, as well as crashing Steam itself.

I have tried the following:

Made a backup of the game on a flash and deleted local PC content. I then proceeded to restore the backup. That didnt work.

I tried using the compatability settings to use it as if it was on Windows 7. I did this on both the launcher and the Game App itself. That didnt work.

I have verified the local cache through Steam. It found 161 files were corrupted or not present. It downloaded the files. But didnt work overall.

I am truly at wits end with this game. Is there something I'm not doing right?

My Specs (if it helps)

Core i7 - 6700U @ 2.8GHz
8GB RAM
AMD Radeon R5 M320 Graphics Card
Windows 8.1

Comment: Try a full delete local content (don't restore from backup), and re-download.  This has happened to be once out of the 300+ games I own, and yeah, it was also a really massive game (40 Gb iirc).

Comment: If the suggestion above by @Nelson doesn't work, try updating your AMD card drivers to the latest Beta drivers: https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-catalyst-windows-beta.aspx.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this is just the mystery of a computer... just upgrade all your drivers, full re-install, and see if you get different errors.  Different errors would actually be a good thing, because it means you changed what's causing it.  Same error may mean something else entirely.

Comment: 161 files corrupt or missing? I'd following @Nelson's advice, do a full delete of Fallout 4's files, and redownload, then verify the cache when the download is done.

Comment: @Nelson it works! Thank you! Now I can explore the commonwealth!

Comment: @Nelson Please convert your comment to an answer, so GipsyD can flag this question as answered. Thanks!